# Как выполнить скрипт в точное время?

Tags: cron, ajax, php, mysql, javascript

Необходимо выполнить скрипт с помощью крона в точное время (например, в 14:00:00), с точностью до секунды. Крон не всегда попадает в это время. Есть идея запустить через крон другой скрипт за 1-2 минуты до окончания, который определит текущее время сервера и рассчитает оставшееся время, и после этого выполнит необходимый скрипт. Возможно ли это сделать более простым способом?

Comment: А как насчет реализовать в скрипте паузу в эН секунд?..

Comment: @deivan, именно это и описывается в вопросе как не самый пряморучный метод.

Comment: так, кто еще *НЕ* написал предложенное автором решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте свой скрипт за несколько минут до нужного времени. А внутри скрипта делайте "активное ожидание" - то есть просто в цикле с интервалом каждые 5-10 секунды проверяйте текущее время и продолжайте выполнение критичного участка.

**Обновление**

Можно, но кто будет перезапускать Ваш сервис, если он упадет? Да и держать его постоянно в памяти нет смысла.

Comment: @KoVadim @StixoTvorec, мне кажется, можно сделать и без крона.

Comment: @KoVadim, как вариант, можно сделать проверку в самом index.php, или при отправке запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Держать постоянно в памяти свой демон, который будет проверять время, напр. раз 10 в секунду, и запускать ваши задачи точнее, чем крон.

Следить за тем, чтобы демон не отвалился и перезапускать его в случае отвала – с помощью [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)'а, как вариант.

Comment: Не лучший вариант.

Comment: Определите критерии хорошего решения.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме Cron, ничего посоветовать не могу. Сам сталкивался. И да, делал запуск одного скрипта из другого.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду at. Я сейчас не могу потестить на большом размахе, но запуск date через at выдал точно :00.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал всё без крона, на файлах и бд. При обновлении страницы идет проверка времени и т.д.