# Почему команды из crontab запускаются чуть хаотично?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, crontab

```
dzmitry@mycomp:~$ crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=dzmitry


*/15 * * * * play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth 3 sine 2000; date >> checktime
dzmitry@mycomp:~$
```

Результат за 3 часа:

```
Sat Jul 30 16:30:05 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 16:46:36 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 17:00:05 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 17:22:31 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 17:30:04 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 17:45:09 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 18:00:10 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 18:16:34 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 18:30:04 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 18:56:45 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 19:05:18 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 19:15:38 MSK 2016
Sat Jul 30 19:30:04 MSK 2016
```

Почему записи не строго раз в 15  минут? Например, выполнениеN: 18:30:04, выполнениеN+1: 18:56:45, разница: 26 (двадцать шесть) минут

Comment: вижу выполнение **строго** раз в пятнадцать минут. не в 14 и не в 16. уточните, пожалуйста, в чём суть вопроса. в разном количестве секунд? так crond не гарантирует «сигналы точного времени». для этого надо что-то другое использовать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнить скрипт в точное время?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378700/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Comment: Ну допустим третье выполнение было в 17:00, а четвертое в 17:22. Разница в 22 минуты. Или вот в 18:30, а следующее в 18:56. Разница в  26 минут

Comment: это **не** ошибка и **не** неправильное поведение программы. «сигналы точного времени» crond **не** гарантирует. если вам нужны именно «сигналы точного времени», то обратите внимание на вопрос, ссылка на который чуть выше.

Comment: Т.е. если указано выполнять раз в 15 минут, а выполняется иногда раз в 22 минуты, иногда раз в 26 минут, иногда раз в 10 минут, то все нормально?

Comment: в приведённом логе видно, что выполняются задачи раз в **пятнадцать** минут. не в **четырнадцать** и не в **шестнадцать**, и уж точно не в **двадцать две** или в **двадцать шесть**. именно раз в пятнадцать минут. точное время выполнения задач crond **не гарантирует**.

Comment: Что-то я похоже принципиально не понимаю. ВыполнениеN: 18:30:04 
ВыполнениеN+1: 18:56:45 Разница: 26 (двадцать шесть) минут

Comment: да, неправильно понимаете. первая **задержка**: 4 секунды, вторая **задержка**: 11 минут 45 секунд. да, такая задержка *редко встречается*, но не более того.

Comment: Ну значит я все правильно понимаю, но может быть не правильно выразился и вы не поняли. Почему разница между, например, выполнением N(18:30:04) и N+1(18:56:45) не 15 минут, пусть и плюс/минус пару минут, а целых 26 минут.

Comment: неправильно понимаете. задача должна была выполниться в 18:30, и была выполнена в 18:30:04. т.е. с **задержкой** в 4 секунды. ключевое слово: задержка. аналогично со следующей задачей. ещё раз: crond не гарантирует точного времени выполнения задач.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin команда была начата в 18:30, и выполнялась 3 секунды и запись в лог была произведена в следующую секунду.

Comment: @strangeqargo, возможно.

Comment: спасибо, что научили синтаксису команды play :) мне пригодится, чтобы колонки будить, а то они каждые 15 минут без звука - выключаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сваппинг, занятые аудио-устройства, незамеченные ребуты, разнообразные тормоза hdd, глюки ОС и другие подобные факторы вполне могут влиять на crontab.

автор:> *Вы похоже правы.Перегрузил компьютер, не включал никаких программ, оставил на три часа. Результат: выполнение команд происходит с нужной периодичностью с точностью до одной секунды*

из комментов мы выяснили, что виноват, в итоге был браузер и ubuntu 14.04, которые совместно и злонамеренно блокировали запуск play до окончания проигрывания видео. Дальнейшее расследование, может быть покажет нам всю подноготную этой грязной игры.

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы поставили запись времени после выполнения команды , возможна ваша команда и выполняется столько времени.

Comment: Команда play должна прогрывает сигнал 2кГц длительностью 3 секунды. Если ее просто вводить, то так и происходит

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас не было какого-нибудь свопинга, ребутов, занятых аудио-устройств и т.д.?

Comment: @strangeqargo Вы похоже правы. Перегрузил компьютер, не включал никаких программ, оставил на три часа. Результат: выполнение команд происходит с нужной периодичностью с точностью до одной секунды

Comment: @strangeqargo, все, кажется разобрался. Дело в браузере. У меня как фон играет музыка с ютуба. Когда она играет, звонка нет. Когда _ролик останавливается, например меняется_, тот звонок, что должен был играть в свое время, играет в этот момент. Более того, если уже должно было прозвучать несколько сигналов, то после остановки ролика все звучат и записываются в лог-файл

Comment: гг, вот что-то такое я и подозревал.  адище конечно. а что за линукс у вас (если линукс)? Если сменишь команду на `/15 * * * * play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth 3 sine 2000 & ; date >> checktime` По идее, будет в бэкграунде выполняться, но не факт, что будет звучать. Но в логе должно быть правильное время.

Comment: @strangeqargo, Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS ; 3.19.0-65-generic

Comment: @strangeqargo а ты запускаешь напрямую, или посредством crontab? Просто, если я запускаю напрямую, даже с работающим ютубом, то все в порядке, писк есть. А вот если ставлю, что бы писк был каждую минуту, то ждет окончания ролика

Comment: @pynix http://stackoverflow.com/a/31236563/5006740 похоже на ответ. если звук из под разных пользователей играет, демон лочит устройство и выигрывает тот, кто его занял первым, под какими пользователем кронтаб или браузер надо проверять.